# SQL: how to create a column to record the length of a user's session time?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which looks like the following (it has been ordered by user_id and timestamp):

[image: before]

I'm looking to create a new feature called session_time, which records how long it has been since the start of a user's session. If there is a gap of more than 20 from one timestamp to the next for a particular user, I would like the session_time to reset to 0. Otherwise, I would like session_time to increase by the gap between the two timestamps.

Here is an example of what I would like the table with the new feature to look like:

[image: after]

I'm struggling to implement this in SQL and would really appreciate any help.

The following creates the sample table to save transcription:

```
CREATE TABLE t (row_id int,user_id int,timestamp int);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (1, 115, 0);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (2, 115, 1);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (3, 115, 3);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (4, 115, 28);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (5, 115, 29);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (6, 115, 0);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (7, 115, 2);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (8, 115, 45);
INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp) VALUES (9, 115, 47);
```

Comment: Could we have the sample data as *text*, preferably as an `INSERT` statement please? Don't force us to do transcription.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sure, will edit my question. When you say ```INSERT``` statement, do you mean 9 lines like this: ```INSERT INTO t (row_id,user_id,timestamp,session_time) VALUES (1, 115, 0, 0);```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have added the insert statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to identify where sessions start.  Then use arithmetic and a cumulative max to get when the session starts:

```
select t.*,
       (timestamp -
        max(case when timestamp - prev_timestamp > 20 or prev_timestamp is null
                 then timestamp
            end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp)
       )
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I'm confused about one point though - what happens in the ```case when``` clause when neither of the conditions are met?

Comment: @nyptop . . . It returns `NULL` which is ignored by most aggregation functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
  select 115 as user_id, 0 as timestamp union all
  select 115, 1 union all
  select 115, 3 union all
  select 115, 28 union all
  select 115, 29 union all
  select 200, 0 union all
  select 200, 2 union all
  select 200, 45 union all
  select 200, 47
)
select *, timestamp - first_value(timestamp) over (partition by user_id, session_num order by timestamp) as session_time
from (
  select *, sum(is_gap) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as session_num
  from (
    select *, if(timestamp - lag(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) > 20, 1, 0) as is_gap
    from mytable
  )
)
```

[image]